# Increase the percentage font size in flot pie chart

Tags: jquery, css, charts, flot, percentage

I have configured a pie chart using the jQuery `Flot` library [here](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/series-pie/)

And I am using the `Default without legend` pie chart, where it displays the `percentage` with `labels`, like below:

```
      $.plot($("#placeholder_pie"), data, {
                series: {
                    pie: {
                        show: true
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    show: false
                }
            });

    }
```

[image]

But as we can see, the `percentage font-size` was too small, so I wanted to increase it, and went through various settings, but wasn't able to do that.

So can anyone please let me know how to increase the percentage font size? Is it possible to increase it?

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying like [`http://jsfiddle.net/L7XY3/`](http://jsfiddle.net/L7XY3/) or [`http://jsfiddle.net/L7XY3/1/`](http://jsfiddle.net/L7XY3/1/) ?

I used

```
function labelFormatter(label, series) {
  return "<div style='font-size:20px;'>" + label + "<br/>" +series.percent + "%</div>";
}
```

to increase font size.

Let me know I am understand your requirement properly or not.

Comment: :Thanks for replying, actually i want it like shown in `http://jsfiddle.net/L7XY3/`, but when i used the code, i am getting an error like `could not draw pie with labels contained inside canvas`

Comment: Please make a fiddle example with your code. That will helps to inspect the issue.

Comment: @shivakrishna If you're getting that error, then your placeholder is too small to hold the labels.  You need to either reduce your font size, increase the placeholder size, or set the labels to be drawn inside the pie instead of outside.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as described by shiva krishna in the first comment.
To solve this I use `Math.round(series.percent)` instead of just `series.percent` in the labelFormatter function.